# How to execute grep inside sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using `sbt` for building my Scala project and I was looking for a way to filter output of any command (like `compile`) by sub-string. In particular, I want to use `grep` in combination with sbt commands. For example `> compile | grep MyFile.scala`, should print only lines where `MyFile.scala` was mentioned.

Is there any way to do that?

```
$ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.5
```

Comment: Although it might not fully meet your needs, did you have a look at sbt's `last-grep` command?

Comment: thank you. It helped me. I guess it is the best option for me. I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible at all.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to grep the output of SBT in interactive mode (tested with sbt 0.13.11) is to use the `last-grep`.

This will re-print the output of the last command and it will take different grep-like arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about doing it from within the sbt console, but how about from your shell?

```
$ sbt "tasks" | grep 'clean'

clean    Deletes files produced by the build, such as generated sources, compiled classes, and task caches.
```

Or for substrings as you mention:

```
$ sbt "tasks" | grep 'class'
  clean   Deletes files produced by the build, such as generated sources, compiled classes, and task caches.

  console   Starts the Scala interpreter with the project classes on the classpath.

  consoleProject   Starts the Scala interpreter with the sbt and the build definition on the classpath and useful imports.

  consoleQuick   Starts the Scala interpreter with the project dependencies on the classpath.

  run   Runs a main class, passing along arguments provided on the command line.

  runMain   Runs the main class selected by the first argument, passing the remaining arguments to the main method.
```

Comment: yeah, I'm aware about this solution, but restarting `sbt` all the time is a bit tedious. I was looking for a way to do it from sbt shell